# How Can I Make A Windows Executable With Pyserial?

Tags: python, py2exe

I am trying to make an executable of a Stackless Python 2.6 program. The setup file is

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['controller.py'])
```

and I run it with

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

However, when I try to run it, it raises an ImportError and says that there is no module named serial. When I try:

```
python setup.py py2exe --includes serial
```

or

```
python setup.py py2exe --includes pyserial
```

the build fails with an ImportError. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You may need to explicitly include the DLL in the packaging.  [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220777/including-pyds-dlls-in-py2exe-builds) discusses it in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had same issue. Upgrading pyserial to 2.5 solved the problem: exec built without additional "includes" contains pyserial.