# py2exe compiles pySerial without errors, but com port doesn't open

Tags: python, serial-port, py2exe, pyserial

I am working on a quick project that uses pySerial to read data from a physical scale. I'm using pygame as the front-end for a simple GUI. I'm trying to use py2exe to deploy the project.

- The project works when run through python, opening serial and reading it as expected.
- The executable compiled by my py2exe setup script runs normally (no import errors)
- The executable does not open serial correctly. Unless I bury the exception that's raised when the serial port can't be found, the program closes at that point.
- With all the serial code dummied out or nested in try / catches, the executable works fine. There is probably not a problem with pygame or the rest of the code.

Here's the relevant code from **main.py**, which is the only file:

```
import os, sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

if not pygame.font: print 'Warning, fonts disabled'


#serial
import serial
import io
import time
```

...

```
def initSerial():
try:
    #The port is hard coded for now
    port = 11
    ser = serial.Serial(port-1)
    ser.baudrate = 2400
    ser.timeout = 0.01 
    sio = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedRWPair(ser, ser))
    print "serial port opened"
    return ser, sio
except Exception, message:
    print "couldn't open serial"
    raise SystemExit, message #The executable dumps here if this line is included
    return None, None
```

And here's my **setup.py**, which I mostly copied from a [tutorial](http://screeniqsys.com/blog/2009/03/20/making-py2exe-play-nice-with-pygame/):

```
#see http://screeniqsys.com/blog/2009/03/20/making-py2exe-play-nice-with-pygame/

from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import sys
import os
import glob, shutil
import pygame
sys.argv.append("py2exe")

VERSION = '1.0'
PRODUCT_NAME = 'Weight Mentor'
SCRIPT_MAIN = 'main.py'
VERSIONSTRING = PRODUCT_NAME + " ALPHA " + VERSION

REMOVE_BUILD_ON_EXIT = True
PYGAMEDIR = os.path.split(pygame.base.__file__)[0]

SDL_DLLS = glob.glob(os.path.join(PYGAMEDIR, '*.dll'))

if os.path.exists('dist/'): shutil.rmtree('dist/')

extra_files = [ ("graphics", glob.glob(os.path.join('graphics','*.png'))),
                ("fonts", glob.glob(os.path.join('fonts','*.ttf'))) ]

INCLUDE_STUFF = ['encodings',"encodings.latin_1",]

setup(windows=[
    {'script': SCRIPT_MAIN}],
     options = {"py2exe": {
         "optimize": 2,
         "includes": INCLUDE_STUFF,
         "compressed": 1,
         "ascii": 1,
         "bundle_files": 3, #unfortunately on x64 we can't use the better bundle files options. So we bundle nothing :(
         "ignores": ['tcl', 'AppKit', 'Numeric', 'Foundation']
         } },
     name = PRODUCT_NAME,
     version = VERSION,
     data_files = extra_files,
     zipfile = None)

if REMOVE_BUILD_ON_EXIT:
     shutil.rmtree('build/')

for f in SDL_DLLS:
    fname = os.path.basename(f)
    try:
        shutil.copyfile(f, os.path.join('dist',fname))
    except:
        pass
```

Normally this setup script also has some code that trims the weight of the distribution with some excludes, but I've dropped those while testing to eliminate excluded packages as the source of the error.

So I figure that there must be something (a DLL? another line in INCLUDE_STUFF?) that I need to add to *setup.py* to make it work correctly with pySerial. I just have no idea what that something is. The py2exe documentation doesn't mention special requirements for pySerial, and my googling hasn't turned up anything.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem having the application behave as it should be when running through python but then not working when the exe was produced out of the script. This may be of help to you: [How Can I Make A Windows Executable With Pyserial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9718675/how-can-i-make-a-windows-executable-with-pyserial)